# Show premise implies conclusion using resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm looking into rules of inference and in particular [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), e.g.

$$((p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ r)) → (q ∨ r)$$

Now in the textbook I see the following example but I don't quite understand it

> Show that the premises `(p ∧ q) ∨ r` and `r → s` imply the conclusion `p ∨ s`.
>    And here are the steps from the textbook to show this:
>
> 1. Rewrite `(p ∧ q) ∨ r` as `(p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r)`
> 2. Rewrite `r → s` by the equivalent clause `¬r ∨ s`
> 3. Using the resolution we can conclude `p ∨ s`

Now I'm having a bit trouble understanding the above. To me the task is to show this:

$$((p ∧ q) ∨ r) ∧ (r → s) → p ∨ s$$

Now while I understand where first 2 steps come from, can't quite get my head around the 3rd one. After first 2 steps this is what we have (I think)

$$((p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r)) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)$$

How it goes from here to conclude that

$$((p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r)) ∧ (¬r ∨ s) → p ∨ s$$

is what I'm having hard time understanding.

I tried to use `Commutativity`, `Associativity` to go from

$$((p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r)) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)$$

to

$$((r ∨ p) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)) ∧ (q ∨ r)$$

Here I see that the first part is a `Resolution`:
 $$((r ∨ p) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)) → (p ∨ s)$$

but can't understand what about: $$∧ (q ∨ r)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extra information we don't need. Since it's connect with an AND, we can discard it if necessary. Using [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination), we know from:
$$
((r ∨ p) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)) ∧ (q ∨ r)
$$

we can infer that:
$$
(r ∨ p) ∧ (¬r ∨ s)
$$

and so by resolution, we conclude that $p \lor s$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about `conjunction elimination`, makes perfect sense now.